# SQL Query to Combine String from 2 list of words?

Tags: sql

I'm trying to run an efficient query from a CRM, in which I can query a list of messages where social media users are reporting their engagement dropped. This is all based upon the user reported verbatim, so there is no ability to query other than messages reported from users in thread.

I have my first set of key words reported in the WHERE clause - these are related to engagement.

I have my second set of key words reported in the WHERE clause - these are related to a decline.

Ideally - I want to write a query to only pull cases where any of the referenced strings in my first WHERE clause are in the same thread of any of the referenced strings in my second WHERE clause

```
SELECT column FROM table

'-- first set of key words --'
  WHERE column like '%view%' OR column like '%view count%' OR column like '%analytics%' OR column like '%audience insights%' OR column like '%engagement%')

  AND 

'-- second set of key words --'
column like '%drop%' OR column like '%decrease%' OR column like '%lower%' OR column like '%fell%' OR column like '%used to%' )
```

Comment: I removed the conflicting DBMS tags. Please add only one tag for the database product you are really using.

Answer (score 0):

you could use RLIKE

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME
WHERE COLNAME RLIKE 'REGEX1|REGEX2|REGEX3'
```